# DPD Label Printing using the PHP API for a Citizen label printer

Tags: php, printing

Any help would be appreciated. We are trying to connect a php system to automatically print DPD labels to a Citizen label printer. We are exploring using php_printer which is installed fine and can see the printer from our code, and the DPD api call is generating new shipments successfully on the DPD website.

**Questions**

1. Firstly, is this the best way to go to send raw print data to a Citizen label printer from a PHP application using php_printer or is there a better way?
2. Secondly, we will be doing some live tests shortly, but there seems to be a formatting issue on the DPD api get Label call where we retrieve the raw citizen print data to send to the printer directly to trigger the print.

**Expected Data from the API example**

```
\M3000\c0000\e\O0220\f290\n\a\LD11PISIH12
2911A0803340387DPD
2911A0603500375www.dpd.co.uk
1911A1003800095Responsible Delivery - CO Neutral
1911A08037802572
2911A0603780354Sender
2911A0603780346GEOPOSTUK LTD
2911A0603780338ROEBUCK LANE
2911A0603780330SMETHWICK
2911A0603780322BIRMINGHAM
------ etc
```

We are receiving the data sample below in our output .txt file in that the slashes are not appearing in the file after file_put_contents and in our readers they either appear as spaces or black circles.

**Actual Data we are receiving**

```
M3000c0000eO0220f290naLD11PISIH12
2911A0803340387DPD
2911A0603500375www.dpd.co.uk
1911A1003800095Responsible Delivery - CO   Neutral
1911A08037802572
2911A0603780354Sender
2911A0603780346GEOPOSTUK LTD
2911A0603780338ROEBUCK LANE
2911A0603780330SMETHWICK
2911A0603780322BIRMINGHAM
```

Can anyone suggest php headers or output settings that we need to configure to ensure nothing is being removed from the request?

**PHP code sample sent to DPD for the Label:-**

```
$shipmentId = 123456789;
$method = '/shipping/shipment/' . $shipmentId . '/label/';

$url = 'https://api.dpd.co.uk . $method;
$options = array(
'http' => array(
    'method' => 'GET',
    'Host' => 'api.dpd.co.uk',
    //'header' => "Accept: text/html\r\n" .
    'header' => "Accept: text/vnd.citizen-clp" .
    "GEOClient: account/" . $account_number . "\r\n" .
    "GEOSession: " . $session . "\r\n"
 )
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
file_put_contents("dpd_test_citizen_clp.txt", $result);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sean, we're having a similar issue, except that sending the command to the printer doesn't seem to work. Would you mind sharing your PHP code to send the command to the printer? cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those people who need to know how to actually print this file, the data is in Citizen PRN format and can be sent to the printer directly by using the Windows `COPY` command.

From the command prompt:

```
COPY /B C:\FILENAME.PRN \\ComputerName\PrinterName
```

You will need to create a printer share for the Citizen printer accessible at `\\ComputerName\PrinterName`

If you are running PHP locally to achieve this, then you can use:

```
file_put_contents("C:\dpd.prn", $data)
exec("COPY /B C:\DPD.PRN \\ComputerName\PrinterName")
```

If you find install PHP locally too daunting or complex, consider using a basic scripting language like AutoHotKey: https://autohotkey.com/

EDIT:
I have since written a nodejs application that you can connect to with a websocket that will copy the data sent to it, to the local citizen printer: https://github.com/MacroMan/DPDLocalPrinter

Comment: do you have an example of how this is installed and used?

Comment: @futureweb do you mean the DPDLocalPrinter utility on GitHub? I've added a README to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Update: This was actually an API change for DPD in that they removed the \ from the returned input. So code above was all fine and the output was as expected.

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of not getting it working I thought I would share our solution. Everything listed above is correct, the only thing we were doing wrong (I feel stupid now!) was copying the API response from [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) rather than doing a `file_push_contents('data.prn', $response)` into a new file.

Copy and pasting the response from postman, or the DPD API docs cuts out all of the bits needed to make it work!